# Jquery incorrectly sort <li> by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I have this `<li>` to sort by id:

```
<ul id="members-list">
   <li id="member_8">
   <li id="member_4">
   <li id="member_7">
   <li id="member_12">
   <li id="member_11">
   <li id="member_13">
   <li id="member_5">
   <li id="member_6">
   <li id="member_9">
   <li id="member_3">
   <li id="member_2">
   <li id="member_1">
   <li id="member_10">
</ul>
```

The code I use:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("li[id*='member_']").sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseInt(a.id.replace('member_', '')) > parseInt(b.id.replace('member_', ''));
    }).each(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.remove();
        $(elem).appendTo("ul#members-list");
    });
});
</script>
```

The result is:

```
<ul id="members-list">
   <li id="member_5">
   <li id="member_8">
   <li id="member_7">
   <li id="member_1">
   <li id="member_2">
   <li id="member_3">
   <li id="member_4">
   <li id="member_6">
   <li id="member_9">
   <li id="member_10">
   <li id="member_11">
   <li id="member_12">
   <li id="member_13">
</ul>
```

The `<li>` are no not sorted correctly, what can cause the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you did not implement the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function correctly. The function is supposed to return a positive number, negative number or zero; you're returning true/false.

So when a.id is less than/equal to b.id the function returns false which is zero-ish; which is treated as *a.id is equal to b.id*; this puts the sorting function off the track.

Solution is to change this:

```
return parseInt(a.id.replace('member_', '')) > parseInt(b.id.replace('member_', ''));
```

To this:

```
return parseInt(a.id.replace('member_', '')) - parseInt(b.id.replace('member_', ''));
```

---

Having said all that, you could rewrite your code using `detach` and a single `appendTo` like this:

```
$("li[id*='member_']").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return +a.id.replace("member_", "") - b.id.replace("member_", "");
}).appendTo("ul#members-list");
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming you don't have the same number twice, you can use this:

```
return (parseInt(a.id.replace('member_', '')) > parseInt(b.id.replace('member_', ''))) ? 1 : -1;
```

Salman A answer works for all cases.

sort() expects the values 1,0,-1 as a return value: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), so you shouldn't use the > sign.